# Heatmap Matrix Graph Where a Column's Data Defines the Matrix Cells

Tags: r, heatmap

I need to make a graph from the next dataframe:

[DATAFRAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qrYc.png)
*There a 80 "Saberes"

I'd like to create a matrix-like heatmap where each 'Saberes' is a cell, and the color of the heatmap is determined by the variable 'Frecuencias'. However, I haven't been able to make it work. I'm somewhat new to R, so I'm open to any advice you can give me :)

This is what I´ve tried.

```
# The mtcars dataset:
data <- mapeo_con_frecuencias[, c("Saberes", "Frecuencia")]
data <- as.matrix(data)

# Default Heatmap
heatmap(data)
```